# Where can I find the Java documentation for "==" equals operand?

Tags: java

I believe "==" is for reference comparison (address comparison). So, I believe this should print out false, but I have an error, Incomparable types: java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Double. When comparing addresses, why would type matter? It's not the same address, so print false. Again, I'm just looking for the documentation. It's a hypothetical question.

```
Integer seven = 7;
Double sevenPointTwo = 7.2;
System.out.println("seven == sevenPointTwo is " + (seven == sevenPointTwo) );
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3   (comment, not answer, since I'm not personally acquainted with the precise details the OP wants)

Comment: @another-dave - Or the more up-to-date (not that this has changed) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeap, I deleted it.

Comment: Note, your question talks of Integer : String, but the example is Integer : Double.  I think these may be different due to the potential for unboxing.

Comment: Thanks -another-dave. The error message is about java.lang.Double.

Comment: This question is 1 vote from being closed. As I've stated twice, I'm looking for a location in the documentation, not an interpretation of the "==" operator. Secondly, the suggested similar question answers how the "==" operand reacts when comparing two objects of the same type. This question's example has objects of different types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The place you find this defined is [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3), which says:

> **15.21.3. Reference Equality Operators `==` and `!=`**
>
> If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the null type, then the operation is object equality.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal (ignoring the case where both values are null).**
>
> At run time, the result of `==` is true if the operand values are both null or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result is false.
>
> The result of `!=` is false if the operand values are both null or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result is true.
>
> While `==` may be used to compare references of type String, such an equality test determines whether or not the two operands refer to the same String object. The result is false if the operands are distinct String objects, even if they contain the same sequence of characters (§3.10.5). The contents of two strings s and t can be tested for equality by the method invocation s.equals(t).

*(their emphasis)*

Equality of objects is about more than where they are in memory. Comparing one type of object to another type of object is never going to yield a true result (see their emphasized part), so rather than have an `==` that will never be true, the compiler tells you that it's an error.

The compiler does this with other errors that can be detected at compilation time, such as code you can't reach.